# execute simple query in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, has-many

Movies has many Relations And Relations belongTo Movies . Relations table has movie _id field.
i want to show list of relations in view of movies model. so in MoviesController.php i have :

```
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid Movie', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    $this->set('Movie', $this->Movie->read(null, $id));
    $cid = $this->Movie->read('Relation.id');
    $cid_extract = Set::extract($cid, 'Relation.id');
    $this->set('planComps', $this->Movie->find('all',array('conditions' => array("movie_id" => $cid_extract))));
}
```

But i see

```
Error:  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Relation.id' in 'field list'

SQL Query:  SELECT `Relation`.`id`, `Movie`.`id` FROM `myproject`.`movies` AS `Movie` WHERE `Movie`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

but the query i need is:

```
SELECT `Relation`.`id` FROM `myproject`.`relations` AS `relation` WHERE `Movie`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

I'm new in cakephp. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->loadModel('Relation');
$records = $this->Relation->find('all', array(
                'recursive' => -1,
                'conditions' => array('Relation.movie_id' => $movie_id),
                'fields' => array('Relation.id')
            ));
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. how can i show this $records in view? I should send it to view?

Comment: `$this->set('records',$records);`. In view you can access records using $records.

Comment: it said : Undefined variable: records [APP\View\Movies\view.ctp, line 43]

Comment: i should set $records in controller and use records in view?